# Sharing web.config fies between sites

Tags: asp.net, web-config, rsa, shared-hosting

Not being a server admin I was wondering, can two ASP.NET websites on the same server sharing a common database use identical web.config files? I am developing a separately-branded companion website for a company with multiple business groups. Both sites have their own URLs but are hosted on the same server and will both communicate with the same database. Since the one site is already setup and running I was hoping I could save time and reuse the web.config in the new site. Will this cause any conflicts with the RSA key and its related cyphervalues?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How much control over the host do you have? (Is this a server you can log in to or a domain provided by a hosting company)?

Comment: Personally I have no control. The client has server admins that maintain the server but they weren't sure on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.  Each website must have it's own web.config in the root folder (at a minimum).

Comment: Thank you, Steve. Real quickly...can they be copies of each other? In other words, each site has a web.config but they're duplicates?

Comment: They absolutely can be duplicates.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you very much.